# Does kivy or kivymd have page indicator like the one for ios with dots?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

Does kivy or kivymd have page indicator like the one for ios with dots? or do I have to code it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a list of the components that [Kivymd supports](https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/wiki)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The names of all the icons can be found here: https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/icon_definitions.py

Perhaps you're looking for one of the following?

"dots-horizontal"

"dots-horizontal-circle"

"dots-horizontal-circle-outline"

"dots-vertical"

"dots-vertical-circle":

"dots-vertical-circle-outline":